# disable the css files containing font face and loading them when window load complete with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Modified=(i want to remove css files containing fonts before they load in document, and when the document complete loading then i want to append those css files back into head so they will be ignored by google page speed insight, you can ignore the code i have written.)

i am trying to disable the fonts before they are loaded into document like removing the css file containing font faces at the document ready function, and when the document loading complete i want to append those css files back into head but the problem is i don't know. how to do this. i am trying to do this in wordpress so $ are replaced with jQuery and wordpress jquery is being used.

here is some code where i am trying to remove some css files and failing. its showing the url in consol log but not removing it. and the function to fetch css files containing font faces is out of my range. if somebody help me with it i will be really thankful.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('link[href]').each(function(){
            let url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            if(url === "//krannaken.com/wp-content/uploads/sgf-css/font-b8f04501e2566c46133fdd3b6c616a08.css"){
                console.log(url);
                jQuery(this).attr('href').remove();
            }
            if(url === "//krannaken.com/wp-content/uploads/sgf-css/font-40569607d7578b60739e8b9717f5c0b8.css"){
                jQuery(this).remove();
            }
            if(url === "//krannaken.com/wp-content/uploads/sgf-css/font-1b552e98c5836178863bfbc4ecd6aa9e.css"){
                jQuery(this).remove();
            }
            if(url === "//krannaken.com/wp-content/uploads/sgf-css/font-0ae462df9c069b6a3ad293ae791fb55c.css"){
                jQuery(this).remove();
            }
        });
```

});

even i am happy with if its in javascript

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? You description doesn't make sense to me. You want to remove CSS only to add it back later?

Comment: Not sure it even makes sense to try that at this point, I think the browser might have already started loading the resources at this time. If anything, those stylesheets should be "disabled" by the server-side coding already, and then "activated" by JS on the client.

Comment: You could [disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) the stylesheets instead of trying to remove them.

Comment: same thought as @cloned. on a side note, you can remove `attr` like this `jQuery(this).attr('href', '');`. But again, why you'd like to remove them as it's already loaded?